Why does this code not render a line in svg?
I reduced the svg to print a horizontal line to that:
<svg width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
        <path id="pathBatteryToGrid" d="M390,250 L110,250"/>
    <linearGradient id="pathBatteryToGridColor" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#ffff00" />
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#00aa00" />
    </linearGradient>
</defs>
<g>
    <use href="#pathBatteryToGrid" fill="none" stroke="url(#pathBatteryToGridColor)" stroke-width="2"/> 
</g>
</svg>

If a modify the svg line to be not horizonal by a small value, it is drawn.
<svg width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
        <path id="pathBatteryToGrid" d="M390,250 L110,250.002"/>
    <linearGradient id="pathBatteryToGridColor" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#ffff00" />
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#00aa00" />
    </linearGradient>
</defs>
<g>
    <use href="#pathBatteryToGrid" fill="none" stroke="url(#pathBatteryToGridColor)" stroke-width="2"/> 
</g>
</svg>

Why does it happen?
